# Paradox in deriving the area of an ellipse

Tags: calculus, integration, conic-sections, polar-coordinates, parametric

We have an ellipse $x=a\cos(\theta)$ and $y=b\sin(\theta)$. We will find the area by adding sectors $\frac12r^2\;d\theta$. Now,

$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^{2\pi}\frac12r^2\;d\theta&=\frac12\int_0^{2\pi}\left(a^2\cos^2\theta+b^2\sin^2\theta\right)\;d\theta\\
&=\frac12\int_0^{2\pi}\left(\frac{a^2+b^2}2+\frac{a^2-b^2}2\cos2\theta\right)\;d\theta\\
&=\left.\frac12\left(\frac{a^2+b^2}2\theta+\frac{a^2-b^2}4\sin2\theta\right)\right|_0^{2\pi}\\
&=\frac\pi2\left(a^2+b^2\right)
\end{align}
$$

Why is it not $\pi a b$?

Comment: You are not using polar coordinates correctly.

Comment: There is no paradox here, just wrong calculations.

Comment: $x=a\cos\theta,y=b\sin\theta$ can not match the polar coordinates $x=r\cos\theta,y=r\sin\theta$, unless $a=b$.